# Adding Header and Footer only on few Pages when printing Html

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-to-pdf

Hi I'm working on generating a pdf from html using browser's print functionality in react.
This is the components of html :

```
    const coverPage = `<div  class="coverPage"></div>`;
    const instructionPage = `<div  class="instructions sun-editor-editable"></div>`;
    const mainContent= `<div  class="main-content"></div>`;
    const pageBreak = `<div class="pageBreakBefore" ></div>`;
    const backPage = `<div  class="backPage"></div> `;
```

mainContant can span over multiple pages. it also contains two more classes .header and .footer. I have a wrapper html in which I'm finally inserting the entire generated html.
this is wrapper html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <style>
      .page-header, .page-header-space,
      .page-footer, .page-footer-space {
        height: 60px;
        background-color:white;
      }
      .page-header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width:100%;
      }
      .page-footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width:100%;
      }
      #contentss  {
         position: relative;
         z-index: 1000;
      }
      @media print{
        .pageBreakBefore{
          page-break-before:always;
        }
    .header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff; /* You can adjust the background color as needed */
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    }

     .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff; /* You can adjust the background color as needed */
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
        
      }
      
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>[[Body Contents]]</body>
  </html>
```

and this is my table format to print the html properly. In tbody im inserting the combined html and in thead and tfoot goes my header and footer for pdf. thead and tfoot occurs on every page when printed. I insert this result html in [[Body Contents]] of above wrapper html

```
export const ResultHTML = `
  <div class="page-header" style="text-align: center"></div>

  <div class="page-footer"></div>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--place holder for the fixed-position header-->
          <div class="page-header-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="contentss"></td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer-->
          <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
`;
```

I replace [[Body Contents]] with the above component html (cover page, instructions, main content etc) when their combined html is generated.
.header and .footer styles in wrapper html allows me to print header and footer on every page but I dont want header and footer to be printed on the cover page and back page.

I have tried almost everything but nothing worked. I tried multiple react libraries as well like html2pdf,jspdf,pdfmake but each of them has image rendering issues or either the html breaks. The browser print functionality gives me the perfect result i just dont want the header and footer on the cover page and back page. Any Idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can set display none for the header and footer on those pages. What exactly is the problem here? (Perhaps include some of the body's html in your question. And if its generated, then the code that generates it.).

Comment: I have inserted my result Html in the question. Its basically table format to print the html in proper format as i found online. and I cant set header and footer to display none as it will hide them on each and every page.

Comment: So basically your "header" and "footer" are fixed positioned so that when the page is scrolled, they are always there. With this approach you dont actually have multiple pages, from a logical standpoint. You only have multiple pages when printing because thats how it works where a new one is created when space is ran out on the previous one (plainly stating the obvious).

Comment: The solution is to not use this strategy for printing. If you dont want to do a lot of new coding, then the easiest course is to remove the header and footer from the print job. How essential is it? (if removing is not an option, then you'll need to build the pages programmatically. Seriously look into a pdf library this time.)

Comment: well after a lot of searching I found a workaround from a very old post on stackoverflow only I managed to remove it from the cover page. here's the link to the post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74949498/13551251 now I have a new problem to solve  thats to print page number on each page, do you know anything about it?

Comment: SInce you dont programatically have multiple pages (just a single page that becomes multiple pages when printed), your code cannot know how many pages will be printed beforehand (nor track a page count while printing). As such, one solution, again, is to generate the pages before printing, e.g. via a pdf library.

Comment: is there any decent library out there that you want to suggest? My html is quite complex and includes images. I tried using jspdf, makepdf, html2pdf each of them either broke my html or the images weren't getting rendered. Other options that are available are not open source.

Comment: I would suggest using a server side library. But this is just how I would do it. PHP is relatively easy to setup and begin coding in. There are pdf libraries for it. Internet search "php pdf library".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion unfortunately I'm working with react and springboot and I'm not allowed to make external api calls so yeah I'm pretty much stuck with this.

Comment: "unfortunately I'm working with react and springboot" ... then wouldn't it be easier to simply not have these extra "print" features you want? I mean, who really cares? I've seen banks not even have footers/headers for transaction summaries for print. It doesn't really matter. Consider that as a solution.